xlsxwriter path not found, the path works in windows explorer
   File "E:\app project\python\pacager\venv\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py", line 354, in close
    raise FileCreateError(e)
xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/Documents/ClassRoutines.xlsx'  

error is shown
from pathlib import Path 
import xlsxwriter 

documents_folder = Path.home() / 'Documents'
file_path = documents_folder / 'ClassRoutines.xlsx'
file_path_str = file_path.as_posix()
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(file_path_str)

path generated: C:/Users/User/Documents/ClassRoutines.xlsx

Error: xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/User/Documents/ClassRoutines.xlsx'

'C:/Users/User/Documents/' exists so  ClassRoutines.xlsx should have been created


What is file_path_str

file_path_str variable converts // to /
for some reason it shows // in xlsxwriter

Xlsxwriter doesn't seem to think the directory exists. Have you tried an additional check like if Path(documents_folder).is_dir(): See if that evaluates True?

then the file wouldn't be created. (the directory exists the path works in windows explorer)

I thought on windows, file path is 'C:\Users\User\Documents'. as you can see from your own error message: "E:\app project\python\pacager\venv\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\workbook.py" it should be back slash, not slash. (slash is for Mac).

it shows // instead of / so the workbook doesn't work

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

then the file wouldn't be created. (the directory exists the path works in windows explorer) You say the file is not created, though not sure how that is relevant to you making a check on the directory status.

@moken I see. I googled as_posix   https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html# I found it odd that a window user would use file_path.as_posix()

Well my problem was with the directory permissions. It looks like due to security reasons, wider permissions needed to modify the file and IDE was not giving a clear traceback to error so I was confused. Running the IDE as admin seem to work.
